# SQL add column based on if statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, concatenation

I have a table with a 4 character (col1) that I would like to:

- split in half
- use an if statement to recode the left 2 characters as specific integers
- concat left onto rght (separated by '.') to generate the fin column below.

| col1 | left | rght | fin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx01 | xx | 01 | 01.1 |
| xy01 | xy | 01 | 01.2 |
| xz01 | xz | 01 | 01.3 |

Bit of a SQL noob so appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: do u need order at fin column after decimal point

Comment: no - there are only three possible values for 'left', so just an if with 3 conditions is required. thank you!!

Comment: You can use sql [case statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As col1 length is 4 digit fixed so here half means 2 digit. You can do ORDER BY operation either full value of col1 or LEFT(col1, 2).

```
-- SQL SERVER
SELECT col1, LEFT(col1, 2) "left"
     , RIGHT(col1, 2) "right"
     , RIGHT(col1, 2) + '.' + CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1)) AS VARCHAR(2)) fin
FROM test
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d76d9c504472f93ed3e4c53b88b94f57

Using CASE statement

```
SELECT col1, LEFT(col1, 2) "left"
     , RIGHT(col1, 2) "right"
     -- , RIGHT(col1, 2) + '.' + CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1)) AS VARCHAR(2)) fin
     , RIGHT(col1, 2) + '.' + CASE LEFT(col1, 2) WHEN 'xx' THEN '1' WHEN 'xy' THEN '2' ELSE '3' END fin
FROM test
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a1f10444fd50c9c1c541c49d8f23344f

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to manually assign 1, 2 and 3 to the "left" values? cast((row number is not the behavior that i want (sorry if this was unclear). thanks!

Comment: @littletimmy please check

Comment: CAST is needed when concat two different type like varchar with int.